# Getting data from websites on C# UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I am a newbie trying to learn the basics on retrieving data from website using C# for universal windows applications. I am having trouble.

For instance, I tried the following code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync("https://uspdigital.usp.br/rucard/Jsp/cardapioSAS.jsp?codrtn=6");
var a = doc.GetElementbyId("almocoSegunda").innertext;
```

The problem is "a" received a null value. I think that html agility pack is not working for this webpage because I noticed it's not downloading the text in the tables.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) class.  Here's [an example of using HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187345.aspx).  After you download the page with `GetStringAsync()`, you can parse it with HtmlAgilityPack's `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this didn't work for me either. I think it's because the text from this page is generated using javascript.

Comment: The you need to use the webbrowser control, (may only be winforms?), or something like http://awesomium.codeplex.com/

Comment: yeah, webbrowser is only on winforms, I tried to mimic the webbrowser technic using webview, but had no success. I will give awesomium a try. Got any hints?